# How to set (wrap: 'circular') (loop) in “auto scroll” plugin in the new version of jCarousel (3.0)?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, autostart

How to set (wrap: 'circular') (loop) in “auto scroll” plugin in the new version of jCarousel (3.0)?

I want the items too loop without stop as in previous version of jCarousel.

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Any kind help would be highly appreicaited.

Comment: @jsor: hi, would you please answer this question too?

Answer (score 12):

The `wrap` option has to be set when initialising the carousel, not for the pagination plugin:

```
$('.jcarousel')
    .jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular'
    })
    .jcarouselAutoscroll({
        target: '+=1',
        interval: 3000
    });
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the carousel still stops when it reaches the last target

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.jcarousel').jcarousel({wrap:"last"}).jcarouselAutoscroll();
```

Comment: Why wrap: "last", I think it should be wrap: 'circular'